# How is Pride the enemy of Hope?

Tags: catholicism, christian-living, pride

The Bible has much to say about hope, especially in Romans chapter 8.  The Old Testament has much to say about pride, which God hates (Proverbs 8:14, for example). As for despair, Christians are encouraged not to despair even when perplexed (2 Corinthians 4:8).

***I can readily understand how despair can destroy hope, but how would pride be the enemy of hope?***

I found this expression in a novel set in the republic of Ireland, where the main characters are educated by Catholic nuns.  Pride and despair are both viewed as sins.
Initially, I would like to explore the views of Catholics to establish if this is part of their beliefs.

***In what way, spiritually speaking, are pride and despair the twin enemies of hope?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumption is the sub-vice of Pride which runs counter to hope and that's the specific kind of pride being talked about here, I think.

> Presumption is here considered as a vice opposed to the theological virtue of hope. It may also be regarded as a product of pride. It may be defined as the condition of a soul which, because of a badly regulated reliance on God's mercy and power, hopes for salvation without doing anything to deserve it, or for pardon of his sins without repenting of them. Presumption is said to offend against hope by excess, as despair by defect.
>
> [Presumption - Old Catholic Encyclopedia](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12403a.htm)

The most common way presumption seems to be manifested is by people assuming they're heaven bound and not fearing God's judgement. It's specifically a sin against hope because it negates hope or the need for hope.

---

They're the twin enemies of hope (hope in salvation) because pride (i.e. Presumption) says I'm good enough (but no one is Good but God) and despair says I'll never be good enough (which is an offense against the Holy Spirit, the unforgivable sin)

Comment: Interesting link between Pride and Presumption, and the extremes of thinking "I'm good enough" and "I'll never be good enough". Both are enemies of hope in God's provision for our salvation.

Answer (score 3):

Pride says I can do it.  It being doing enough to save myself, doing enough penance for forgiveness, doing enough earn enough merits to attain heaven.

Despair says no one can do it.  It being saving us, redeeming us, keeping us.

Hope says I know who my redeemer is, I know who saved me, I know where I am bound.

Comment: Appreciate this spiritual application.

Answer (score 1):

Stubbornness is a detrimental aspect of pride mentioned in Jeremiah 13:9 and 10:

> 9 “This is what the LORD says: ‘In the same way I will ruin the pride
> of Judah and the great pride of Jerusalem. 10 These wicked people, who
> refuse to listen to my words, who follow the stubbornness of their
> hearts and go after other gods to serve and worship them, will be like
> this belt—completely useless! (NIV)

This scripture also indicates that pride and stubbornness can occur in individuals as well as in a collective of people. As you mentioned, Romans 8 also speaks about hope:

> 24 For in this hope we were saved. But hope that is seen is no hope at
> all. Who hopes for what they already have? 25 But if we hope for what
> we do not yet have, we wait for it patiently. (NIV)

Someone who sees no hope is in despair and stubbornly resists change. Someone proudly in the illusion of already being saved also has no hope and stubbornly resists change. But the humble one tries to remain in hope for the adoption of “sonship (vs 23) and is saved.

Why is pride or over confidence dangerous? Because:

> ...you do not even know what will happen tomorrow. What is your life?
> You are a mist that appears for a little while and then vanishes.
> 15Instead, you ought to say, “If it is the Lord’s will, we will live
> and do this or that.” 16As it is, you boast in your arrogant schemes.
> All such boasting is evil. James 4:14-16 (NIV)

and because:

> Pride goes before destruction, a haughty spirit before a fall. Proverbs 16:18 NIV

So although pride and despair seem quite opposites, both can be viewed as the twin enemies of hope. Despair is the absence of hope on the one extreme, and pride is the denial of the necessity of hope on the other extreme. Having hope is the humble balanced view in between.

Although I am not aware if this is also a catholic view, I suppose it is a quite universal thought/interpretation.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Did you notice that Romans 8:24 says “For in this hope WE WERE SAVED”?  “For it is by grace you HAVE BEEN SAVED, through faith – and this not from yourselves, it is the gift of God” (Romans 2:8). No if's, no but's, no maybes. There is no illusion involved in our salvation. It’s a done deal, and that’s why our hope.is built on faith - the assurance of God's promises to his adopted children.

Comment: @Lesley, imagine you were drowning in the water. Then a ship came and saved you. Then you jumped overboard again. Or in other words the ship of your faith has sunk.  Yes you were saved but it does not imply you will live. See 1 Timothy 1: 18-20 (the example of Hymenaeus and Alexander). But because the topic you start in your commend is a different topic, i already wrote "is saved in my answer here".

Comment: I appreciate where you’re coming from – that nobody knows they are saved because they might stumble and fall before they die, or before Armageddon arrives, whichever happens sooner. But I reject the analogy between someone physically drowning then jumping overboard again after being rescued. Faith is a gift from God.  People can reject the gift but when God saves, He saves to the uttermost.  No amount of striving or working at salvation can do anything to add to what Christ Jesus has already accomplished. However, to pursue this point is to go off-topic. Could you ask a question about it?

Comment: I guess we both agree on that being saved is undeserved kindness and there is no way to "earn" it to be saved. But I would argue that Jesus Christ offers salvation to everyone, but not everyone has faith and accepts his salvation and then remains faithful. Because people have a free will, there is also the issue that people can change their mind and attitude for either good or bad. I will try to find a better analogy or maybe formulate a question about this.